# Are Capitol citizens allowed to move out to live in the Districts?

Tags: the-hunger-games

Like if you wanted to live in one of the districts because of better scenery or something, are Capitol citizens allowed to not live in the Capitol?

Comment: I don't think there is anything we have learned that would prohibit such a choice, but given the current "climate of culture" I feel anyone making that decision would be looked upon suspiciously; both before and especially after the rise of Katniss. Additionally, IMO I can see no one from the capital who would wish to live outside of the capital. I'm sure they are happy just visiting...

Comment: You mean like Effie? I recall she was free to move - however her "legal status" was still from the capitol (although she stayed in districts). So she wouldn't be subject to reaping or disciplinary measures.